# How to play a notification alert sound when the browser window is minimized and when a notification comes from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat, google-talk

I have a requirement where i need to play a notification sound only when the browser window is minimized similar to what GTalk does.

I've tried it using JQuery's $(window).blur() but it only plays it when I manually blur it but not when the notifications comes and the window is blurred.

Here is the fiddle that I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/zfUnm/

Actually this is a chat notification that i have to play only when the browser is minimized.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you getting the notification from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they don't play it when minimize. They will call it every time the new notification comes, but when window is active, they disable the sound.

```
var isactive = false;

function playSound(){
    if (isactive) return;
    playWav...;
}

onNotificaitonComes = playSound;

$(window).focus(function(){
    isactive = true;
}).blur(function(){
    isactive = false;
});
```

You can find out more method here [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)